# How to repeatedly read lines from command prompt into WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, stream, command-prompt

I am attempting to open a command prompt process, input a command, then repeatedly read the first 5 lines.

I am able to read the lines once using the `ReadLine()` function; however, once the position is at the 6th line, I need to go back to the first one.

I have tried the `Seek()` function and I've tried changing the Position of the stream (both shown as comments below) but I get the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Stream does not support seeking.'

How can I go back to the first line and re-read those 5 lines?

Is there a different way that I should approach this problem?

```cs
    Process process = new Process();
    
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"/";
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.Start();
    
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("someCommand");
    
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream);
    
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadLine());
        }
    
        //streamReader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    
        //streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `DiscardBufferedData` method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata?view=net-6.0

e.g.:

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream);

while (true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadLine());
    }

    streamReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
}
```